# SES Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, symfony-mailer

in my composer.json i have this

```
"symfony/amazon-mailer": "^6.0",
"yiisoft/yii2-symfonymailer": "^2.0",
```

in my main.php i have this

```
 'mailer' => [
            'class' => \yii\symfonymailer\Mailer::class,
            'viewPath' => '@frontend/views/user/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'dsn' => 'ses+smtp://XXXXXXXXXXX:'.urlencode('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').'@email-smtp.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:587',
             ]
]
```

when i send an email using my contact from, this show up in my log files.

```
2022-06-14 13:40:53 [][-][-][error][yii\symfonymailer\Mailer::sendMessage] Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "XXXXXXXXXXX" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN", "PLAIN". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 Authentication Credentials Invalid".". Authenticator "PLAIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 Authentication Credentials Invalid".".
2022-06-14 13:40:49 [][-][-][info][application] $_GET = []
```

my username and password is correct, any idea what im missing? thanks.

#### Additional info

| Q | A |
| --- | --- |
| Yii version | 2.0.45 |
| Yii SymfonyMailer version | ^2.0 |
| SymfonyMailer version | v6.0.8 |
| PHP version | 8.1.6 |
| Operating system | Ubuntu |